# ¿Como puedo traducir este código javascript en vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Recientemente estoy empezando a utilizar Vue.js y se me hace un poco complicado traducir el siguiente código de **Javascript** a **Vue.js**, por este motivo necesito apoyo, por favor:

```
const toggleButton = document.querySelector(".dark-light");
const colors = document.querySelectorAll(".color");

colors.forEach(color => {
    color.addEventListener("click", e => {
        colors.forEach(c => c.classList.remove("selected"));
        const theme = color.getAttribute("data-color");
        document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", theme);
        color.classList.add("selected");
    });
});

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
});
```

El contenedor de vue:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        
    },
    methods: {
        
    }
})
```

Comment: Pues no es tanto traducir, ya que en Vue puedes escribir perfectamente código js nativo y te va a funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que quieres hacer un *toggle* entre temas seleccionando un color.
Puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente.

Las propiedades que están dentro del objeto `data` de la instancia de `Vue` es el `state` de tu app y son reactivas, es decir, que si las modificas se re-renderiza la app y también  se pueden usar en la `template`. Por lo tanto, he definido una propiedad `colors` que contiene un conjunto de colores que se pueden seleccionar. Y hago un loop sobre el array para renderizar los colores y añadir el evento `@click` y la clase `.selected` si el color coincide con el seleccionado.

Y en `methods` he definido un método llamado `toggleTheme` que recibe el color que se ha seleccionado y lo setea a `selectedTheme`

Vue tiene una manera declarativa de añadir eventos, no hace falta usar el `elem.addEventListener`. Puedes usar los eventos que ofrecen mirando la documentación.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    colors: [
        'dark',
      'light',
      'green',
      'blue'
    ],
    selectedTheme: 'light',
  },
  methods: {
    toggleTheme: function(color) {
        // alert(color)
      this.selectedTheme = color;
      document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", this.selectedTheme);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button
      v-for="color in colors" 
      @click="toggleTheme(color)" 
      :class="{ selected: color === selectedTheme}"
  >{{ color }}</button>
</div>
```

Mira la [documentación](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html) esta muy bien